# Google map has extra Width

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am using `100%` and `margin:0;` but still google map coming width it's extra with and page is fluiding when map is open.

```
#map {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    height: 400px;
}
```

This is what i am using for map. but still,

it's look like this at the right side of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent element which contains #map might be having some extra width. To confirm, please try to give a fixed pixel width to #map and check if that solves the problem. Might be able to help you more if you could share your HTML code.

Comment: I check it,  and solved the problem. thanks for advise.

Answer (score 0):

@Barbie

You can hide Extra space by just giving a property.
Also extra map isn't important as well.
:
overflow: hidden;